# Adding a new column to a may to many relationship in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many

A have this mapping:

mapping.HasManyToMany(x => x.SubVersions).ParentKeyColumn("ParentId").ChildKeyColumn("SubVersionId").Table(
                "VersionLinks");

This will create a table VersionLinks with 2 columns(ParentId,SubVersionId). Is it possible to have in this table another column (ex. CreateDate) that will be filled automaticly (DateTiem.Now) without creating a new entity VersionLink with fields Parent, SubVersion, Date?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to create the new CreateDate column manually with a default `getdate()` value, but I'd just create a new entity for VersionLink and convert the `many-to-many` to `many-to-one`s

Answer (score 0):

For auto updating the date property, take a look at using the [IPreUpdateEventListener](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/29/nhibernate-ipreupdateeventlistener-amp-ipreinserteventlistener.aspx).

As for the mapping table, I'm pretty sure you're stuck with having to create a composite-element. I had a similar issue where I wanted to add `sort` and `weight` columns. I ended up with the following mapping:

```
<bag
  name="criteria"
  access="field"
  table="assessment_criterion_map"
  fetch="subselect"
  cascade="save-update">
  <key column="assessment_id"/>
  <composite-element class="WeightedCriterion">
    <parent name="assessment"/>
    <many-to-one
      class="Criterion"
      name="criterion"
      access="field"
      column="criterion_id"
      cascade="save-update"
      fetch="join"/>
    <property name="Weight"/>
    <property name="SortOrder" column="sort_order"/>
  </composite-element>
</bag>
```